# Bottom navigation bar not showing/working?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

This is my home screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:quotationbox/screens/Drawer/drawer.dart';

import '../Dashboard/CategoryFragment.dart';

import '../Dashboard/FilterFragment.dart';

import '../Dashboard/HomeFragment.dart';

import '../Dashboard/NotificationFragment.dart';

import '../Dashboard/ProfileFragment.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override

  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();

}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override

  void initState() {

    super.initState();

  }

  void navigationTapped(int page) {

    setState(() {

      _currentIndex = page;

    });

  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> _allPages = [

      HomeFragment(),

      CategoryFragment(),

      NotificationFragment(),

      FilterFragment(),

      ProfileFragment(),

    ];

    return Scaffold(

      drawer: MyDrawer(),

      body: _allPages[_currentIndex],

      bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),

    );

  }

  BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar() {

    return BottomNavigationBar(

      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,

      fixedColor: Colors.red,

      currentIndex: _currentIndex,

      onTap: navigationTapped,

      items: [

        BottomNavigationBarItem(

          icon: ImageIcon(

            AssetImage("images/app_images/home.png"),

          ),

          label: "Home",

        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(

          icon: ImageIcon(

            AssetImage("images/app_images/category.png"),

          ),

          label: "Category",

        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: ImageIcon(

              AssetImage("images/app_images/notification.png"),

            ),

          label: "Notification"

        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: ImageIcon(

              AssetImage("images/app_images/calendar.png"),

            ),

         label: "Filter"

        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: ImageIcon(

              AssetImage("images/app_images/profile.png"),

            ),

         label: "Profile"

        ),

      ],

    );

  }
```

//This is my home fragment

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

import 'package:quotationbox/screens/Dashboard/ProfileFragment.dart';

import 'package:quotationbox/screens/Merchant/merchant_list.dart';

import '../../colors_constant.dart';

import '../../utils/common_background.dart';

import '../Drawer/drawer.dart';

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

import '../Offer/myofferscreen.dart';

import '../Quotation/Job/postjob.dart';

class HomeFragment extends StatefulWidget {

  const HomeFragment({super.key});

  @override

  State<HomeFragment> createState() => _HomeFragmentState();

}

class _HomeFragmentState extends State<HomeFragment>  {

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final items = [

    Image.asset('images/app_images/ads.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,height: 180,),

    Image.asset('images/app_images/ads.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,height: 180,),

    Image.asset('images/app_images/ads.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,height: 180,)

  ];

  int currentIndex = 0;

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: AppColors.darkgreen,

      key: _scaffoldKey,

      drawer: MyDrawer(),

      body:

      CustomScrollView(

        slivers: [

          SliverFillRemaining(

            hasScrollBody: false,

            child: Column(

              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

              children: <Widget>[

                Container(

                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(

                      top: 60.0, left: 15.0, right: 10, bottom: 30.0),

                  child: Column(

                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                    children: <Widget>[

                      Row(

                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

                        children: [

                          Align(

                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

                              child: GestureDetector(

                                onTap: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer(),

                                child: Container(

                                  height: 20,

                                  width: 25,

                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                                    image: DecorationImage(

                                      image: AssetImage('images/app_images/ic_menu.png'),

                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,

                                    ),

                                  ),

                                ),

                              )

                          ),

                          Expanded(

                            child: Align(

                              alignment: Alignment.center,

                              child: Container(

                                child: ElevatedButton(

                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(

                                    // backgroundColor: AppColors.yellowColorContainer,

                                    backgroundColor: AppColors.yellowColorContainer,

                                    side: const BorderSide(

                                        width: 3, color: AppColors.yellowColorContainer),

                                  ),

                                  onPressed: () {

                                    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(

                                        builder: (context) => PostJob()));

                                  }, child: Text("Request Quotation",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 15),),

                                ),

                              ),

                            ),

                          ),

                          //Expanded(

                          //  child:

                          Align(

                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,

                            child: GestureDetector(

                              onTap: (){

                                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(

                                    builder: (context) => ProfileFragment()));

                              },

                              child: Container(

                                //color: Colors.white,

                                child: Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),

                                    child: CircleAvatar(

                                      radius: 20.0,

                                      backgroundImage:

                                      NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),

                                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

                                    )

                                ),

                              ),

                            ),

                          ),

                          // ),

                        ],

                      ),

                    ],

                  ),

                ),

                Expanded(

                  child: Container(

                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(

                      color: Colors.white,

                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(

                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),

                        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),

                      ),

                    ),

                    child: SingleChildScrollView(

                      child: Container(

                        decoration: baseBackgroundDecoration,

                        child: Column(

                          children: [

                            Padding(

                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0,right: 0,top: 20,bottom: 10),

                              child: Container(

                                height: 180,

                                // decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                //     border: Border.all(

                                //       color: Colors.grey.shade400,

                                //     ),

                                //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))

                                // ),

                                child: CarouselSlider(

                                  options: CarouselOptions(

                                    autoPlay: true,

                                    aspectRatio: 2.0,

                                    enlargeCenterPage: true,

                                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {

                                      setState(() {

                                        currentIndex = index;

                                      });

                                    },

                                  ),

                                  items: items,

                                ),

                              ),

                            ),

                            // DotsIndicator(

                            //   dotsCount: items.length,

                            //   position: currentIndex,

                            // ),

                            Container(

                              child: SmoothPageIndicator(

                                controller: controller,  // PageController

                                count: items.length,

                                effect:  ExpandingDotsEffect(

                                  dotColor: Colors.grey,

                                  dotHeight: 7,

                                  activeDotColor: Colors.yellow,

                                ),

                                // dotHeight: 16,

                                // dotWidth: 16,

                                // jumpScale: .7,

                                // verticalOffset: 15,// your preferred effect

                              ),

                            ),

                            SizedBox(

                              height: 30,

                            ),

                            Row(

                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                              children: [

                                Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),

                                    child: Text("Latest Merchant",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),)),

                                Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),

                                    child: GestureDetector(

                                        onTap: (){

                                          Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(

                                              builder: (context) => MerchantListScreen()));

                                        },

                                        child: Container(child: Text("See all",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 15,color: Colors.redAccent),))))

                              ],

                            ),

                            merchantList(),

                            SizedBox(

                              height: 20,

                            ),

                            Row(

                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                              children: [

                                Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),

                                    child: Text("Premium Client",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),)),

                                Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),

                                    child: Text("See all",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 15,color: Colors.redAccent),))

                              ],

                            ),

                            clientList(),

                          ],

                        ),

                      ),

                    ),

                  ),

                ),

              ],

            ),

          ),

        ],

      )

    );

  }

  Widget merchantList(){

    return Container(

        height: 180.0,

        child: ListView.builder(

          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

          itemCount: 3,

          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>

              Padding(

                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,right: 5),

                child: Card(

                  child: Container(

                    width: 150.0,

                    child: Column(

                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

                      children: <Widget>[

                        Container(

                          child: Image.asset("images/app_images/electric.png",fit: BoxFit.cover,),

                        ),

                        Container(

                          child: Text("Electric"),

                        )

                      ],

                    ),

                  ),

                ),

              ),

        )

    );

  }

  Widget clientList(){

    return Padding(

      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,right: 5),

      child: Container(

          height: 180.0,

          child: ListView.builder(

            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

            itemCount: 3,

            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>

                Card(

                  child: Container(

                    width: 150.0,

                    child: Column(

                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

                      children: <Widget>[

                        Container(

                          child: Image.asset("images/app_images/adidas.png",fit: BoxFit.cover,),

                        ),

                        Container(

                          child: Text("Adidas"),

                        )

                      ],

                    ),

                  ),

                ),

          )

      ),

    );

  }

}
```

I don't know why Bottom navigation bar is not working in my app.

Comment: Can you update your question [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

it works here

***home_screen.dart***

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void navigationTapped(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = page;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _allPages = [
      const HomeFragment(),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: _allPages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }

  BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      fixedColor: Colors.red,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: navigationTapped,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: "Home",
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.category),
          label: "Category",
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_sharp),
            label: "Notification"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_sharp), label: "Filter"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Profile"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

***home_fragment.dart***

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class HomeFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeFragment({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeFragment> createState() => _HomeFragmentState();
}

class _HomeFragmentState extends State<HomeFragment> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final items = [
    Image.asset(
      'images/app_images/ads.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 180,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      'images/app_images/ads.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 180,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      'images/app_images/ads.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 180,
    )
  ];

  int currentIndex = 0;

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: const Drawer(),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 60.0, left: 15.0, right: 10, bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

                          children: [
                            Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () =>
                                      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer(),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 20,
                                    width: 25,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            'images/app_images/ic_menu.png'),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )),

                            Expanded(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Container(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      // backgroundColor: AppColors.yellowColorContainer,

                                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,

                                      side: const BorderSide(
                                          width: 3, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "Request Quotation",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            //Expanded(

                            //  child:

                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 20.0,
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                          'https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ),

                            // ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          // decoration: baseBackgroundDecoration,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 0, right: 0, top: 20, bottom: 10),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 180,
                                  child: CarouselSlider(
                                    options: CarouselOptions(
                                      autoPlay: true,
                                      aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          currentIndex = index;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    items: items,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                                  controller: controller, // PageController

                                  count: items.length,

                                  effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                                    dotColor: Colors.grey,
                                    dotHeight: 7,
                                    activeDotColor: Colors.yellow,
                                  ),

                                  // dotHeight: 16,

                                  // dotWidth: 16,

                                  // jumpScale: .7,

                                  // verticalOffset: 15,// your preferred effect
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 30,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  const Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Latest Merchant",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 20),
                                      )),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {},
                                          child: Container(
                                              child: const Text(
                                            "See all",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: Colors.redAccent),
                                          ))))
                                ],
                              ),
                              merchantList(),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              const Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Premium Client",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 20),
                                      )),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "See all",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.redAccent),
                                      ))
                                ],
                              ),
                              clientList(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget merchantList() {
    return SizedBox(
        height: 180.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
            child: Card(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 150.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "images/app_images/electric.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: const Text("Electric"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget clientList() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 180.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Card(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 150.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "images/app_images/adidas.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: const Text("Adidas"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am uploaded two type of custom navigation bar follow this this and get code and modify as you want

https://github.com/pravind002/bottom_tab_bar

and another repo name is -
fix_bottom_tab

you guys can refer this .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).